# Copying buffer with std::copy

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a video encoder, I want to copy buffers using vectors for some reason `std::copy` is only copying the first character. my goal is to copy the buffer and write them to a file using `fwrite`.

I am using Google Native Client which does not allow me to have `fwrite` directly from the main thread, so I created a new thread and I have to move the buffer to `fwrite`

I tagged multi threading with this questions to get your feedback on this approach dealing with buffers.

```
std::vector<char> buffer_(4);
char header[4];
header[0] = 'D';
header[1] = 'K';
header[2] = 'I';
header[3] = 'F';

unsigned dataArraySize = sizeof(header) / sizeof(char);

std::copy(&header[0], &header[dataArraySize], buffer_.begin());
std::stringstream ss;
std::string s;



for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer_.begin(); it!=buffer_.end(); ++it)
{
    char c = *it;
    ss << c;
    ss >> s;
    Logger::Log(s);
}
```

For the output I only get D four times

Comment: @DimChtz That is the same as the OP has.  [The vector is being populated correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fba93acdf2c04767).  The issue resides in the for loop

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: In the context of the shown code, your `std::copy` call looks correct. but there's no need for it, just do e.g. `std::vector<char> buffer_(std::begin(header), std::end(header));` and the vector will be initialized with the data from the array. Note that I only speak in the context of code ***as you show it to us***. If you, for example, passes the array to a function you can't use the `sizeof` trick to get its size.

Comment: In your loop, I would use `Logger::Log(std::string(1, c))` and get rid of `stringstream`.

Comment: Either do as @Jarod42 suggests or `ss.clear();` after each extraction (i.e., after `ss >> s;`)

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL As I have [already shown](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fba93acdf2c04767) the copy is fine.  The problem is with the for loop.

Comment: Would it be possible that the issue is related to multithreading, e.g. racing conditions on the vector or conflicts on the use of dataArraySize between threads ?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am using GDB but since it is based on Native Client of Chrome I need to debug inside chrome which is not the easiest task. I am not developing this code completely I am just proofing the concept on a later stage I will hire a developer but I need to know how it is done

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa You can still use something like [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and `cout`s to check what is going on.

Comment: @NathanOliver this is the first time I know about it actually. thanks

Comment: @Angew thanks for the correction, I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy is fine, it is the conversion from char to string which is wrong, you may just use the appropriate constructor

```
for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer_.begin(); it!=buffer_.end(); ++it)
{
    char c = *it;
    Logger::Log(std::string(1, c));
}
```

or simply

```
for (char c : buffer_) {
    Logger::Log(std::string(1, c));
}
```

And, potentially, depending of your logger, concatenate to form one unique string:

```
Logger::Log(std::string(buffer_.data(), buffer_.size()));
```

Comment: it worked fine now, I am testing it to copy buffers. thanks